# How to select the highest value in one column for every day by title in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

I expect result like this:

[image]

I tried this query but it isn't returning what I need. I don't know if I need to use different function or so...

```
SELECT ProjectTitle, TimeByDay,TaskCumulativeWork       
FROM epmtaskcumulativebyday
WHERE TaskCumulativeWork = (SELECT MAX (TaskCumulativeWork) FROM epmtaskcumulativebyday AS c WHERE c.ProjectTitle = epmtaskcumulativebyday.ProjectTitle)
ORDER BY ProjectTitle ASC, TimeByDay ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think aggregation does what you want:

```
select ProjectTitle, TimeByDay, MAX(TaskBaselineCumulativeWork)
from t
group by ProjectTitle, TimeByDay;
```